# adding tags together using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I recently saw the following:

```
$('h2 + p').hide()
```

where the html was:

```
<h2>hi there</h2>
 <p> try again</p>
```

the p tags got hidden but not the h2 tags.  could someone explain what $('h2 + p') does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `+` char in css is the [Adjacent sibling selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors).

It gives you the ability to select the next-immediate element.

For example - if you want to select every `p` element that is after an `img` element and give it a margin, you can use:

```
img + p {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

The actual style will be applied to the `p` element (and not the `img` element). Note that this works exactly the same as `ul li {background: red}` the red background will be applied to the `li` element that is inside the `ul`, but not the `ul` itself.

The following is a more complex example:

```css
p {
  border: 1px solid red;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
div {
  border: 1px solid blue;
}
div + p {
  border: 1px solid black;
  background: purple;
}
```

```html
<p>
 Some paragraph
</p>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<p>
 Some paragraph
</p>
<p>
 Some paragraph
</p>
<div>text</div>
<div>text</div>
<p>
 Some paragraph
</p>
```

Comment: thanks.  appreciate the help

Comment: @DCR you are welcome to accept it.